# MarkerOptions position() set value is different from Marker getPosition() in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my Android application, I'm using **Google Map** to point some locations. But what I mark as ***latitude*** and ***longitude*** value is different from what I'm getting when click on a **Marker**. Here is the relevant code

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public class MyClass extends SupportMapFragment{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mMap = getMap();

    myMethod();

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            LatLng latLng =  marker.getPosition();
            Log.d(TAG, "# latLng.latitude : " + latLng.latitude + " # latLng.longitude : " + latLng.longitude);
            /*
            * Print for the above Log statement is 
            *
            * # latLng.latitude : 45.446733371796135 # latLng.longitude : 6.97720717638731
            *
            */      
        }
    }
    }

    private void myMethod(){
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(coords.getDouble(1), coords.getDouble(0)));
        Log.d(TAG, "# latitude : " + coords.getDouble(1) + " # longitude : " + coords.getDouble(0));
        /*
        * Print for the above Log statement is 
        *
        * # latitude : 45.44673337246575 # longitude : 6.977207233013699
        *
        */
    }
}
```

Those printing values are almost same ***but not*** exactly. Can I know why is that? Because I need to get the exact value I'm feeding to the Map when I click on a particular Marker. If it is because how I include the value to the Map, how should I change it?

Comment: This kind of difference is connected with how Google save/handle this information. I cannot find a reference but as I remember it was said that up to 6 decimal places could be expected to be the same. You can define 'small enough difference' and use it to compare defined/used and actual values.

Comment: @AntoJurković thanks. I continue implementation depend on your suggestion. If you can able to find the reference, please update it as the answer. Then I can accept it.

Comment: Did any one got answer for this same issue is faced by me.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same bug as here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5353

As one commentor pointed out, the LatLng's are being flattened to floats and when retrieving them to doubles again they lose their precision.

I found that getting the lat/lngs into strings and stripping everything but the first 8 characters before comparing them seems to work:

```
            String lat1 = String.valueOf(marker.latitude).substring(0, 8);
```